# How to return a value inside my formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

In google sheets I have this `=SUMIFS('401'!$E:$E,'401'!$C:$C,"SITE",'401'!$D:$D,"BUILDING")`.  I have a bunch of pages (401,402,403,...etc.), but I don't want to have to type each formula for each page.  I put all my page names down column A.  So if I have 401 in cell A1 how do I write this formula so it returns the value that's in A1.

Comment: You could use the INDIRECT() function to get the value from A1 and use it in the path.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`=SUMIFS(indirect(A1&"!$E:$E"),indirect(A1&"!$C:$C"),"SITE",indirect(A1&"!$D:$D"),"BUILDING")`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this is not possible in google sheets without using scripts. best you can do is to hardcode it like:

```
=SUMIFS({401!E:E; 402!E:E; 403!E:E}, 
        {401!C:C; 402!C:C; 403!C:C}, "SITE", 
        {401!D:D; 402!D:D; 403!D:D}, "BUILDING")
```

which could get long so better to use query:

```
=QUERY({401!C:D; 402!C:D; 403!C:D}, 
 "select sum(Col3) 
  where Col1 = 'SITE' 
    and Col2 = 'BUILDING'")
```